# RPi as Bluetooth headset with PipeWire

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, pipewire

I'm trying to setup my RPi4 as BT headset (RPi OS Bookworm).

The expected scenario is connect the phone to RPi device via Bluetooth and be capable to use the speakers and USB microphone connected to RPi.

I've the implementation of this via PulseAudio using few PulseAudio bluetooth related modules. However latest versions of Raspberry OS are based on PipeWire as I see.

Is it possible to do this via PipeWire ?

I've found this example but not understand its internals.
https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2022/09/02/using-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-bluetooth-speaker-with-pipewire-wireplumber/

Maybe there is some book about PipeWire internals ?